# StructureMap's ThreadLocal scope and WinForms

Tags: winforms, structuremap

I'm attempting to hook up NHibernate in a WinForms application using StructureMap to handle the Sessions. In my Web apps I could configure StructureMap to create a new Session per HttpContext and then I could hook into Context.EndRequest event to handle commit and cleanup.

Now I'm trying to figure out a similar approach for WinForms. I assume that if I use the ThreadLocal scope that StructureMap will create a Session per event, but how can I hook into an end event to commit and cleanup?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.80).aspx
if you use the pattern in the4 example, you can do it in the out side the end of the while loop, right?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "event" in your second paragraph?  Do you specifically mean a .Net "event"?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I was talking about a Button click event, or something similar.